# How does "narrowing" work when converting int to char in C++?

Tags: c++

I'm a beginner with C++ and had a question about conversions. When converting int to char values, what happens when 127 is exceeded on the ASCII table?

For example,

```
using namespace std;

int main()
{
double d = 0;
while (cin>>d){
  int i = d;
  char c = i;
  int i2 = c;

  cout<<"d=="<<d<<endl;
  cout<<"i=="<<i<<endl;
  cout<<"c=="<<c<<endl;
  cout<<"i2=="<<i2<<endl;
  cout<<"char:("<<c<<")"<<endl;
}
}
```

Now if the use inputs 150, i becomes 150 as i = d, c becomes û as c = i, which means to me that int 150 = char û

BUT when the int i2 is outputted on the screen, given that int i2 converts char c back into an integer, i2 == 106

My assumption is that int i2 would also be 150.

I'd appreciate if someone could explain this to me as I'm struggling to grasp the concept. I've read that since char can hold 1 byte of information whereas int can hold 4 bytes of information, the value is "narrowed". I'm not entirely sure what that means however!

Comment: The `int` is a `signed int` by default. The `char` is a `unsigned char` by default. That means the `int` can also display negative value, as opposed to the char, which can only display positive integers up to 255. When you explicitly declare the `int` as `unsigned int`, the value stays the same (as long as you dont exceed 255).

Comment: @Sunburst275 -- `char` can be either signed or unsigned; it's up to the implementation. There is no default.

Comment: @PeteBecker True, but that holds for every data type then, doesnt it? For example, a `int` could be 4 bytes on one system but 8 bytes on another. And as far as I know, Windows implicitly declares the `char` as a `unsigned char`, or am I wrong?

Comment: @Sunburst275 -- this is far removed from the question, so let's not go on with discussions of the signedness of `char` here. Ask a question!

Comment: @PeteBecker Yes, forgive me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How does “narrowing” work when converting int to char in C++?

The width of an integer type is roughly the number of bytes (or bits) it contains. So, one type is narrower than another if it has fewer bytes (or bits).

Consider a physical manifestation of `int` - it's an index card with eight boxes marked on it, and we can write one digit in each box. Maybe it's going to be read by one of those automated optical systems, but anyway we're not allowed to squeeze more digits on there or write outside the boxes.

Now, we have an equivalent card representing a `char` - it has two boxes marked on it.

The `char` card can be physically narrower as well, to really hammer home the analogy, but the important thing is that you can only write two digits.

So, in base 10, an `int` card can store 0-99,999,999, and a `char` can store 0-99.

Now, I give you an `int` card with the number `123` written on it, and ask you to copy the value onto a `char` card. What can you do? You can discard the hundreds digit that doesn't fit, and just write `23`. Or I guess you can just throw up your hands in horror and refuse. Typically we want computers to do the former.

**This** is a narrowing conversion. The `char` is physically too small (narrow) to fit all the information an `int` can contain.

---

Finally, to describe the actual `int` and `char` types, we can either use binary (in which case we can only use digits `0` and `1`, and the `int` card has thirty-two boxes while the `char` card has eight), or we can leave our index cards the same size if we write our digits in base 16 instead of base 10.

There is a further complication in that `int` is signed, so we also need to represent negative values too in our fixed number of digits. The `char` *may* be signed or unsigned - it's implementation dependent. If you're interested, you can look up *two's complement*, which is the most common way of storing signed values, but in general half of the values you can store, are going to be negative.

So roughly, the two ways a narrowing conversion can do the wrong thing are:

1. the narrower type just doesn't have enough digits, so some are cut off
2. the narrower type *can* fit all the digits, but is signed, and that particular pattern represents a negative number in the narrow type (assuming it was positive in the wide one)

Comment: Wow! I appreciate the answer and your analogies! This was very helpful, thanks for taking the time to thoroughly answer my question! Take care!